# Setting placeholder text for the default blank option created in an angular dropdowns?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, ng-options

### **Question**

How do I add placeholder text to blank option created by angular `ng-options`.I would like the blank option of my drop downs to say "please select a size"

Caveat:
* to note: it's a extra weird cuz I have  the size collection being split(',') because it's not an array*

### [Live Code Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/djwruftr/3/)

**HTML:**

```
<form ng-app="app" ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <div class="color-pick" ng-repeat="(key, val) in productData.colors_and_sizes.data">
        <input type="radio" name="colors" ng-model="$parent.myColor" ng-value="key" />
        <img ng-click="$parent.myColor = key" ng-src="{{val.swatch_image}}" alt="">{{key}} 
        <div class="size-pick" ng-show="$parent.myColor==key">
            <select ng-model="$parent.mySize" ng-options="size for size in val.sizes.split(',')"></select>
        </div>
    </div>
    myColor: {{myColor}}<br/>
    mySize: {{mySize}}
</form>
```

**JS:**

```
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.controller('Ctrl', function ($scope, $filter, $http) {
 $scope.productData = {
  "colors_and_sizes": {
    "data": {
      "Black": {
        "swatch_image": 'http://lorempixel.com/50/50',
        "sizes": "X Small, Small, Medium, Large, Xlarge, XX Large"
      },
      "Blue": {
        "swatch_image": 'http://lorempixel.com/50/50',
        "sizes": "X Small, Small, Medium, Large, Xlarge, XX Large"
      }
    }
  }
};

});
```

Comment: hey why you delete the previous question ([On ng-change grab index of ng-option](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25256187/on-ng-change-grab-index-of-ng-option)), i was about to post the answer

Comment: undelete the question so that i can post the answer

Comment: Hey @NidhishKrishnan so sorry! I thought I had it but I didnt.

Comment: Actually [simple search should get you more answers](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=specify%20default%20option%20for%20angular%20ng-option&safe=off)..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see here http://jsfiddle.net/jg42xsop/ 
some people saying that we should use ng-init instead using $parent

```
<form ng-app="app" ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <div class="color-pick" ng-repeat="(key, val) in productData.colors_and_sizes.data" ng-init="item = this">
        <input type="radio" name="colors" ng-model="item.myColor" ng-value="key" />

        <img ng-click="item.myColor = key" ng-src="{{val.swatch_image}}" alt="">
            <p>{{key}} </p>

            <div class="size-pick"  ng-show="item.myColor==key">
            <select ng-model="item.mySize" ng-options="size for size in val.sizes.split(',')">
                 <option value="">Please choose a size</option>
            </select>

            </div>

            <p>  myColor: {{myColor}}</p>
            <p> mySize: {{mySize}} </p>
            <hr/>
        </div>
</form>
```

Comment: I feel stupid for not trying that lol.  Thanks for the advice.